# Android Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, cocos2d-x

I'm keep getting this error while build apk file with option `minifyEnabled true`.

Application build process and installation been success but failed to launch with this error.

I have tired to find the the class library. I'm not much familiar with Android app development, please help me with this,

**Error stack-trace**

```
05-11 11:44:09.307 10196-10196/? E/cutils: to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
05-11 11:44:09.307 10196-10196/? E/cutils: to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
05-11 11:44:09.308 10196-10196/? E/cutils: to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
05-11 11:44:09.308 10196-10196/? E/cutils: to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
05-11 11:44:09.393 10196-10196/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcll.zzbax
05-11 11:44:09.394 10196-10196/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcll.zzs
05-11 11:44:09.405 10196-10211/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbhe.zzf
05-11 11:44:09.647 10196-10216/? E/JniHelper: Failed to find static method id of setAnimationInterval
    Failed to find static java method. Class name: org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxRenderer, method name: setAnimationInterval, signature: (F)V 
05-11 11:44:09.840 10196-10216/? E/JniHelper: Failed to find static method id of setAnimationInterval
    Failed to find static java method. Class name: org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxRenderer, method name: setAnimationInterval, signature: (F)V 
05-11 11:44:09.872 10196-10216/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 11342
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxDownloader
        at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(Native Method)
        at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:73)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxDownloader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.game-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.company.game-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(Native Method) 
        at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:73) 
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494) 
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

**gradle.properties**

```
PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=14
PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=22
PROP_APP_PLATFORM=14

# Supported ABIs are [armeabi,arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86].
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:x86
```

**build.gradle**

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.game"
        minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                if (!project.hasProperty("PROP_NDK_MODE") || PROP_NDK_MODE.compareTo('none') != 0) {
                    // skip the NDK Build step if PROP_NDK_MODE is none
                    targets 'game'
                    arguments 'NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9'
                    arguments 'APP_PLATFORM=android-' + PROP_APP_PLATFORM

                    def module_paths = [project.file("../../cocos2d").absolutePath,
                                        project.file("../../cocos2d/cocos").absolutePath,
                                        project.file("../../cocos2d/external").absolutePath]
                    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                        // should use '/'
                        module_paths = module_paths.collect { it.replaceAll('\\\\', '/') }
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(";")
                    } else {
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(':')
                    }

                    arguments '-j' + Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
                    abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect { it as String })
                }
            }
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDir "src"
        res.srcDir "res"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        assets.srcDir "../../Resources"
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            if (!project.hasProperty("PROP_NDK_MODE") || PROP_NDK_MODE.compareTo('none') != 0) {
                // skip the NDK Build step if PROP_NDK_MODE is none
                path "jni/Android.mk"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true // Here
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=0'
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true // and here
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=1'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':libcocos2dx')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in E:\developSoftware\Android\SDK/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

#-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
#-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0
-keep public class com.google.firebase.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.**

-keep public class com.google.ads.** { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
```

This is a Cocos2d-x v3 c++ Game. Thanks

Comment: On which OS version are you running it?

Comment: @Sagar MacOS 10.12.6

Comment: I mean Android OS version

Comment: @Sagar Android version 4.2.2

Comment: was the answer not useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JobScheduler` API is was introduced from API 5.0. So it won't work on older versions like 4.2.2 as a result you encounter the error

For versions lower than 5.0, use `Firebase JobDispatcher`. Refer this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling) for more details.

> Firebase JobDispatcher is an open-source library that provides an API similar to JobScheduler in the Android platform. **Firebase JobDispatcher serves as a JobScheduler-compatibility layer for apps targeting versions of Android lower than 5.0** (API level 21).

You should also update `compileSdkVersion` to 26 or 27 from 14.