# android error cannot find class JobSchedular

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am using android studio 3.1. This is my build file

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.appcomponentexample"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

I get error:

> cannot find symbol class JobSchedular

when I try to build when I use JobSchedular class. I dont know what is wrong.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285606/android-could-not-find-class-android-app-job-jobscheduler/50285841#50285841) ?

Comment: I checked your solution by changing the minSdkVersion to 23 but still i am encountering the same problem

Comment: Have you added `import android.app.job.JobScheduler;` in your class?

Comment: Its working thanks. The typeahead of android studio is not showing me any class from the android.app.job package, also I had to manually type the import statement. I think this can be a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot find symbol class JobSchedular

Happens when you haven't imported the JobSchedular properly. Add import statement to your class:

`import android.app.job.JobScheduler;`

Since JobScheduler is supported from 5.0 keep in mind the consideration for backward comparability. Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285606/android-could-not-find-class-android-app-job-jobscheduler/50285841#50285841) for more details.